# Load a javascript object from file in nodejs, parse error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having trouble while trying to load the following javascript object from a file with NodeJS:

```
{
    queries:{
            user:"SELECT * FROM users WHERE $1 = ?"
    },
    user:function(identifier){
            return this.queries.user.replace('$1', "user_"+identifier);
    }
}
```

With the require function:

```
var queries = require('./components/queries');
```

I get a parsing error on line 4, unexpected ',' right after the queries ending curly bracket.

I'm not sure what is wrong with this object since I can declare it in chrome console without any trouble, so I bet the issue is related with the way I include this piece of code in my main script. But I don't know how to include it properly.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In commonJS you should use the `exports` object to set access to module variables.

```
exports.queries = {
    queries:{
        user:"SELECT * FROM users WHERE $1 = ?"
    },
    user:function(identifier){
        return this.queries.user.replace('$1', "user_"+identifier);
    }
}
```

And then add it like this:

```
var q_mod = require('./components/queries');
var queries = q_mod.queries;

//logs "SELECT * FROM users WHERE $1 = ?"
console.log(queries.queries.user);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 ways to do what you want:

1. Change the extension of the file to `.json`
2. Export the content as a node.js module:

   ```
   module.exports = /* the object */
   ```
3. Read and parse it as a json file:

   ```
   fs.readFile('path/to/file', function (content) {
       var queries = JSON.parse(content.toString());
   });
   ```

Comment: JSON, does not allow functions, and will fail during parsing.

Comment: you are right, I did not pay attention to the content, just read the problem